# URL Encryption for Ids

Tags: javascript, php, security, encryption

I want to ask some question regarding encryption and security point of view. Basically, I want to encrypt my URL to hide the Ids. Tell me which is the best method to do it ? I have read about md5, SHA256, RSA encryption.

I want to clear one thing that the method which you will told me should be application in both JavaScript and php.

And one more question, which encryption method are used by Facebook, instagram and twitter ? Please share me an authenticate link for confirmation of their encryption method method.

Comment: the only limitation of urls is to use any encryption with A-Z and numbers 0-9, so the other charchers like : ; , & ~  # @  are not acceptable.

Comment: Sounds like you are confusing encryption with generation of (pseudo-random) ID values …

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, if I get it right, you want to send secret values to a server using GET requests - the values are to be added to the URL as parameters, and you wish to encrypt them to protect them.

I do not recommend this. It would (probably) involve giving the end user a web page that has your encryption algorithm on it. An attacker could replace that page when it is first sent to your end user, and modify it to contain their own code.
If you insist on doing this, you could use any cryptographic algorithm (note that MD5 and SHA256 that you mention aren't encryption algorithms but cryptographic hash functions). You could use RSA, but a symmetric algorithm like AES is faster, if you can find a way to exchange keys in a secure way.

What you should do, is hide your communications using TLS or a similar protocol. In this way you are using the built-in cryptography that practically every computer has.
The values that need to be communicated in secret can be sent via a POST request. This has the additional advantage that it will be easier to protect your system from replay attacks.

Answer (score 0):

> Basically, I want to encrypt my URL to hide the Ids. Tell me which is the best method to do it ?

#### What People Want To Do Here

[image: Some encryption function is used to deterministically retrieve the ID]

#### What People Should Do Instead

[image: Use a separate column]

---

Use `random_bytes()` and one of `bin2hex()` or `base64_encode()`. If you use Base64, make the number of bytes you generate an even multiple of 3 (e.g. `random_bytes(24)` for a 32-character string).

You can also use [URL-safe base64](https://github.com/paragonie/constant_time_encoding) like so:

```
<?php
use ParagonIE\ConstantTime\Base64UrlSafe;

$token = Base64UrlSafe::encode(random_bytes(24));
```

But encryption is simply [the wrong tool for the job](https://paragonie.com/blog/2015/09/comprehensive-guide-url-parameter-encryption-in-php).

Answer (score -1):

This is encryption you have mentioned that is used for security reasons in PHP when you are saving password into DB. Then you can use such encryption.it converts original text into encrypted form.it is much harder to hack encrypted password.it's important technique for security reasons.